# Proper use of "Because of" followed by a "verb + ing"

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> This is because of your computer not being connected to the Internet.

If this is not, what's the proper structure for using `verb + ing` after `of` (especially "because of")?

Comment: I think it's syntactically valid, but Andrew Lott's suggestions are the more commonly used patterns.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I disagree. I think the OP's sentence is fine, if not superior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you'd be better off saying one of the following:

> This is because your computer is not connected to the Internet.

-or-

> This is due to your computer not being connected to the Internet.

The first sentence simplifies the point and removes potential grammar mistakes.

[This page](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/because.html) has a breakdown explaining the difference between the word pairs "because of" and "due to" which helps in the second example. Basically, "because of" grew up as an adverb & "due to" grew up as an adjective. "This" is then the noun modified by the prepositional phrase.

Comment: Structurally [This is because of] + [Noun phrase] is valid syntax, and "your computer not being connected to the Internet" is a noun phrase. But I agree your suggestions sound more natural, because they are more commonly used.